# Rspec: How to verify if a record has been deleted?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created a simple Rspec test to verfiy if a model created has been deleted.  However, the test fails because the model still exists.  Can anyone provide any assistance on how to determine if the record was actually deleted?

```
RSpec.describe Person, type: :model do

let(:person) {
    Person.create(
      name: "Adam",
      serial_number: "1"
    )
  }
  
  it "destroys associated relationships when person destroyed" do
  person.destroy
  expect(person).to be_empty()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have two choices. You can test that:

1. A record was removed from the database

   ```
   it "removes a record from the database" do
     expect { person.destroy }.to change { Person.count }.by(-1)
   end
   ```

   But that doesn't tell you which record was removed.
2. Or that the exact record does not exist in the database anymore

   ```
   it "removes the record from the database" do
     person.destroy
     expect { person.reload }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
   end
   ```

   or

   ```
   it "removes the record from the database" do
     person.destroy
     expect(Person.exists?(person.id)).to be false
   end
   ```

   But that does not make sure that the record existed before.

A combination of both could be:

```
    it "removes a record from the database" do
      expect { person.destroy }.to change { Person.count }.by(-1)
      expect { person.reload }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
    end
```

Comment: Note that the correct way to write that is `expect { person.reload }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)` instead of `expect(person.reload).to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)`

Comment: @dani-sc Thanks for bringing this up. I fixed my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 8):

I think the following is a nice way to test a specific record has been removed with one expectation, while ensuring your testing the result of the action and not just the state of your test subject.

```
it "removes the record from the database" do
  expect { person.destroy }.to change { Person.exists?(person.id) }.to(false)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

When you delete a record from a database, an object still persists in memory. That's why `expect(person).to be_empty()` fails.

RSpec has the [`change`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/change-matcher) matcher. ActiveRecord has the [`persisted?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted?) method. It returns false if a record is not persisted in a database.

```
it "destroys associated relationships when rtu destroyed" do
  expect { person.destroy }.to change(Person, :count).by(-1)
  expect(person.persisted?).to be_falsey
end
```

`destroy` is a method of a framework. As far as I know, you don't need to test its methods.

Comment: This is not thread-safe. If you have another test running in parallel, `Person.count` can be changing for other unrelated tests running at the same time.

Comment: It can be more specific `change(Person.where(name: 'Adam', serial_number: '1'), :count).by(-1)`

Comment: Still not thread-safe. Even if you pin it down tight enough to be satisfactory, a year later someone's going to copy-paste your code into some other test, and now you'll have two "Adam-1" users potentially existing at the same time. (Or failing to create at the same time)

Comment: Anyway it's one of the default ways to achieve the goal.

Comment: @DavidHempy It works if you use the default `use_transactional_fixtures = true` config option to run each example in a transaction.

Comment: `expect(person.persisted?).to be_falsey` can be changed to 

`expect(person).not_to be_persisted`

Answer (score 1):

You could test the behaviour like so:

```
expect do
  person.destroy
end.to change(person, :persisted?).to false
```

If you test the behaviour you get two expectations for the price of one! ie: you can assert the before and after in one spec.

Also, the reload will raise an error, you could test that (I had to do this for some associations).

```
expect do
  person.destroy
  person.reload
end.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```